# background image in Outlook 2010 (email newsletter)

Tags: html, html-email, outlook-2010

I've seen this discussion back and forth, and I know traditionally background image is *NOT* supported in outlook 2010. But I have also *seen* it done. Some designs require live text.

What is the ultimate synopsis, just don't use -- or try to hack? If a hack, what is the best one? *(most supported)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the design is not reliant on absolutes, I say go for it. Support is as large as it has ever been on background image usage and with some tweaks and 'hacks' you can get your emails looking great (even on Outlook!).

Best place to go is [bulletproof backgrounds](http://backgrounds.cm/) they will give you the code (HTML/CSS and VML for outlook) for both a bg image for a TD and a bg image for whole email. This is a great leaping off point and helps do most of the leg work for you right off the bat.

When positioning your children over the image in parent container, I would make sure to reference [CSS compatability](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) across each email client and do acid test after acid test to make sure it is displaying as you wanted.

It may take a bit of extra work, but the results can be more than worth it.

Comment: Mhmm. I've seen all that info; was looking for more code based answers

Comment: If you have seen that info then you have the "code based" answers. Outside of writing the code for you, I don't know what more you need? I answered your question with my opinion and references that backed it up. The "best back" for outlook is to use VML.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as correct. bulletproof backgrounds literally does everything for you

Comment: Well.. Agree to disagree, sir. But out of good faith, I'll accept this answer, but everyone know; I did not use this, and still omitted the background image!

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance and thank you lejimmie for your support.  I am at a complete loss as to what exactly you are looking for. The ONLY way to insert background imagery into Outlook is through VML - which is what Bulletproof backgrounds uses. If you can give more insight into exactly what you are looking for, maybe I can better assist.